# RiotJS (& web2py): Keep two elements in sync

Tags: web2py, riot.js

With RiotJS I created a simple element that has a contenteditable div in it for the user to modify (myFunction will style it according to some criteria).

Now I want to have that element at the beginning and at the end of my website, and they should be kept in sync with each other... is that possible at all?

If not, is it possible to have a one-way-data-binding (modifications in the top element will show up in the bottom one, but not necessarily vice versa)?

Alternatively it would be also ok to simply have the text (not editable, and not with the same riot element) shown at the bottom...

RiotJS element: (Code is functional so far, there might be some small errors in that piece of code though because it's a cut down and slightly modified version of what I have working :-))

```
<my-element>
  <div id="content" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="{myFunction}">{editableText}</div>
  <style>...</style>
  <script>
    this.editableText = opts.text
    ... // more content
  </script>
</my-element>
```

Mounting in HTML:

```
<html>
<!-- start of page content -->
<my-element></my-element>
<script src="{%=URL(r=request,c='static/js/riot',f='my-element.tag')%}" type="riot/tag"></script>

{%element_text_or_empty = XML(T(someText.content)) if someText else ''%}

<script>
    var textToUse = "{%=element_text_or_empty%}";
    riot.mount('my-element', {text: textToUse})
</script>

<!-- more content -->

<!-- repeat my-element with same (edited) content as above -->
<!--   what to write here?  --> 
</html>
```

Note: I'm using web2py framework, that's where the

```
{%element_text_or_empty = XML(T(someText.content)) if someText else ''%}
```

part comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but:

```
var textToUse = "{%element_text_or_empty%}";
```

should be:

```
var textToUse = "{%=element_text_or_empty%}";
```

Note the missing "=".